# Get specific lines out of HTML page and put into String

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I am trying to parse a specific area of html from this webpage:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Ringo_Starr&prop=text&section=0&format=txtfm&disablepp&redirects
```

*[Please note this is not the source page, it displays html tags but I am interested in the actual source of this page (Ctrl+u)].*

Specifically, I am looking to put all of the lines that begin with:

```
<span style="color:blue;">&lt;p&gt;</span>
```

into a String.

[image]

Here's how I'm trying to solve -- but I seem to be way off:

```
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Ringo_Starr&prop=text&section=0&format=txtfm&disablepp&redirects").get();   
      Elements elements = doc.select("span");
      for (Element e : elements) {
           if(e.text().equals("&lt;p&gt;")){
               System.out.println("now get that whole line");
           }
     }
```

Note: I am using jsoup here -- but would a straight regex would be more effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight regex may be a better idea. Try this for starters:

```
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("^<span style=\"color:blue;\">&lt;p&gt;</span>.+&");
```

Here, `^` starts the line, the `<span style="color:blue;">&lt;p&gt;</span>` is matched literally, we then have one or more [non-line-terminator characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt):

> The regular expression . matches any character except a line terminator unless the DOTALL flag is specified.

and the `$` specifies end-of-line.

Comment: You need to escape quotes in the Pattern parameter

Comment: Also, it is `Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("^<span style=\"color:blue;\">&lt;p&gt;</span>.+&");`. Your example doesn't compile.

Comment: @BackSlash Sorry, just got back. Yes, my bad. Too used to an IDE tha does it for me :/

Comment: @hexafraction Also change the pattern declaration, yours won't compile, Pattern doesn't have that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just write

```
System.out.println(e.nextElementSibling().text())
```

And you also have to check for

```
e.attr("style").equals("color:blue;")
```